Parts of Humans
What does the following image represent? The answer consists of 10 letters in total.



I think the 10-letter answer here is:

 PIRATE FLAG

Because...

 The star rating appears to be a little over 3 out of 5. Since the decimal expansion of π is 3.141... it isn't too much of a stretch to think that this might be cluing a value of PI. Plus we have RATE from rating... Since the whole thing appears in a flag design, this together gives us PI+RATE+FLAG, i.e. PIRATE FLAG.

Is there a way to confirm this answer? Yes!

 Look at the title... A SKULL AND CROSSBONES (i.e. a common design seen on a pirate flag) could be described as '(body) parts of humans'!


Well done :) The answer I had in mind was actually J---- R----. Funny, I didn't even check how many letters PF had. Nonetheless you solved it!

@Prim3numbah Ha, yes both answers work well given the set-up here :)

Stivs answer is better since it actually elucidates the rebus’ logic. I think the question is better without a ‘find an example step’ imo. All the rebuses I have seen never required it.

and there I was thinking about middle fingers...
